# Can an Android app make a post on Facebook and later get the number of likes on that post?

Tags: android, facebook

I want my app to post on Facebook and later query that same post, so that I can find the number of likes it received.

Is it possible? How do we do it?

Comment: Why do you need to know numbers of likes?

Comment: @WizKid I need that information to make statistics data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publishing API documentation from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed)

The result is the post id, so just save this somewhere in the local storage with other post ids.

When you want to get the number of likes, use:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{YOUR_POST_ID}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

You must set `summary = true`

This returns a `summary` element with a `total_count` field.

[Documentation can be found here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it and feedback later.